# OpenVPN with fragment does not allow internet traffic on Android

Tags: openvpn, ping, android

Good day all

My server config uses a fragment setting of 1000 which I found most optimal for Windows/Linux users pass through,

however after adding the same script with supporting certs to Android OpenVPN, not even pings to google go through, I removed the fragment setting on the Android config however this did not change anything, tried pushing fragment too, no results

I would like to keep my fragment setting ofcourse, any work-arounds/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragment [isn't supported on Android](https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-android-faq.html). However, as fragment needs to be specified on both client and server, just removing it from the client side isn't enough and removing it from the server will cause issues for your other clients.

Now, is it really necessary to use `fragment`? From [the manpage](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/manuals/65-openvpn-20x-manpage.html)

> It should also be noted that this option is not meant to replace UDP fragmentation at the IP stack level. It is only meant as a last resort when path MTU discovery is broken.

Comment: thanks for the response, adding the fragment option seemed to improve not only ping by 10% (+/-20ms improvement) but increase throughtput down and up by about 20% both ways, however, would you recommend "playing around" with the mtu settings rather? I have tried editing mtu settings with the mss fix, but that seemed to deny throughput of any traffic when connected

Comment: my max mtu is 1470 available on my server, I tried explicilty setting the mtu at values between 1470 - 1400 with mssfix = "mtu" - 40, this causes all traffic to stop between the server and client

Comment: In all cases I've seen not messing around with MTU worked just fine so I have no idea why you might have these issues. I'd start with no options regarding the MTU or mss or fragment whatsoever and work from there. If you suspect path mtu issues, [this](http://packetlife.net/blog/2008/aug/18/path-mtu-discovery/) might be an interesting read.